# Android fetching values from Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello so I've been strugging for awhile now. I want to consult someone about my code. I want to apply
a coloring function to my app.

When the person presses the button when it's at its:

- `GREEN` state it updates the value on the database to `BEING HOUSEKEPT`
- `YELLOW` state when pressed sends `READY FOR INSPECTION` RoomStatus
- `RED` state when pressed sends `READY FOR HOUSEKEEPING` RoomStatus

It was working earlier but when I tried to restrict the users that users who are Housekeepers can't access the RED STATE which are for House Keepers, I inserted somewhere in my code where I want to implement it.

I'm going over loops here can somebody tell me where I did wrong?

Here's my code:

```
        Button room1;
        private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabase, mFirebaseDatabase1, mFirebaseDatabase1room;
        private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseInstance;
        private DatabaseReference referenceroom1;
        private  String roomStat;



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_navi_to_scan2);
            mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            mFirebaseDatabase1 = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("Rooms");
            mFirebaseDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("Users");
            mFirebaseDatabase1room = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("Rooms").child("Room1");
            referenceroom1 = mFirebaseDatabase1.child("Room1").child("RoomStatus");

            room1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rm1Btn);




            mFirebaseDatabase1.child("Room1").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() { //attach listener

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { //something changed!


                    for (DataSnapshot locationSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String location = locationSnapshot.getValue().toString();

                        if (location.equals("READY FOR HOUSEKEEPING")) {
                            room1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                            roomStat = "Green";
                        } else if (location.equals("BEING HOUSEKEPT")) {
                            room1.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                            roomStat = "Yellow";
                        } else {
                            room1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                            roomStat = "Red";
                        }


                        if (roomStat.equals("Green")) {

                            room1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                    String message = "BEING HOUSEKEPT";
                                    DatabaseReference reference = mFirebaseDatabase1.child("Room1").child("RoomStatus");
                                    reference.setValue(message);
                                    Intent next1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ReaderActivity3.class);
                                    startActivity(next1);
                                }
                            });


                        } else if (roomStat.equals("Yellow")) {
                            room1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                    String message = "READY FOR INSPECTION";
                                    DatabaseReference reference = mFirebaseDatabase1.child("Room1").child("RoomStatus");
                                    reference.setValue(message);
                                    Intent next1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ReaderActivity2.class);
                                    startActivity(next1);




                                }
                            });

                        } else {
                            room1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                    String message = "READY FOR HOUSEKEEPING";
                                    DatabaseReference reference = mFirebaseDatabase1.child("Room1").child("RoomStatus");
                                    reference.setValue(message);
                                    Intent next1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ReaderActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(next1);



                                    //I ALSO WANT TO PUT A CONDITION HERE FETCHING  userType from Structure
                                    // mFirebaseDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("Users").child("userKey");
                                    //but doing this would mean that I would have to put a listener inside, would that be okay? I tried when this
                                    //was working at first but it didin't and now the whole thing is not working


                                }
                            });

                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { //update UI here if error occurred.

                }
            });



        }
```

Here's my structure:

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

[image: screenshot 3]

Can you help me identify what's the problem with how i implemented this?

[image]

Comment: What is inside those children from Room1? Can you add a new screenshot with that data?

Comment: @Alex Mamo I have edited the question pelase see the pic thanks

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing wrong, try debugging. Android is buggy nowadays, especially when you're connecting to a cloud database. In the left side of the run button the bug shaped one. Debug.

Or maybe you could try to show your `location` which is your string, to check if you pulled the right info from your database. You can use logs. A guide can be found here

https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html